# TypeError and AttributeError

Tags: python

I've searched a lot of ways on the Internet, but I still can't solve it. I'm a beginner of python. Please help me to have a look.

```
import hashlib
import time
import traceback
import win32api
import win32clipboard as clip
from io import BytesIO
import win32con
from PIL import Image


def setImage(data):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    try:
        clip.OpenClipboard()  
        clip.EmptyClipboard()  
        clip.SetClipboardData(win32con.CF_DIB, data) 
        m.update(clip.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_DIB))
        clip.CloseClipboard()
        return m.hexdigest()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        setImage(data)

def copyPicMain(imagePath, width = 600, height = 480, internal=0,    
 notResize = False):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    try:
        clip.OpenClipboard()
        m.update(clip.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_DIB))
        clip.CloseClipboard()
        pre_md5 = m.hexdigest()
    except TypeError:
        # if clip is empty
        traceback.print_exc()
        print('empty')
        pre_md5 = ''
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        clip.OpenClipboard()
        m.update(clip.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_DIB))
        clip.CloseClipboard()
        pre_md5 = m.hexdigest()
    img = Image.open(imagePath)
    output = BytesIO()
    if not notResize:
        img = img.resize((height, width), Image.BILINEAR)
    img.convert("RGB").save(output, "BMP")
    data = output.getvalue()[14:]
    output.close()
    new_md5 = setImage(data)
    print(pre_md5, new_md5)
    time.sleep(internal)
    win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_CONTROL, 0, 0, 0)  # ctrl key code 17
    win32api.keybd_event(86, 0, 0, 0)  # v key code 86
    win32api.keybd_event(86, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)  # key up 
    time.sleep(internal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    imagePathList =    [r'C:\Users\strives\Desktop\panda.png',r'C:\Users\strives\Desktop\black.png',r'C:\Users\strives\Desktop\1.png']
for imagePath in imagePathList:
    copyPicMain(imagePath)
```

**Debug result:**

C:\Users\strives>python C:\Users\strives\Desktop\test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\strives\Desktop\test.py", line 28, in copyPicMain
    m.update(clip.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_DIB))

**TypeError: Specified clipboard format is not available**

empty

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\strives\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-

packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2656, in open  fp.seek(0)

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\strives\Desktop\test.py", line 60, in 
    copyPicMain(imagePathList)

File "C:\Users\strives\Desktop\test.py", line 42, in copyPicMain
    img = Image.open(imagePath)

File "C:\Users\strives\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2658, in open   fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'**

**EDIT**

I recompiled it and the following error occurred.

C:\Users\strives>python C:\Users\strives\Desktop\test.py

cfdb447aa6b20d45ba79b5802a677454 1aa0384b01ed1e2ecd6158c52a1355a5
1aa0384b01ed1e2ecd6158c52a1355a5 c28f8947d15edb17752ec5f503a1b82b

**Traceback** (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\strives\Desktop\test.py", line 27, in copyPicMain
 clip.OpenClipboard()

pywintypes.error: (5, 'OpenClipboard', 'Access is denied.')
c28f8947d15edb17752ec5f503a1b82b cfdb447aa6b20d45ba79b5802a677454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you made a mistake in

```
                     for imagePath in imagePathList:
                          copyPicMain(imagePathList)
```

you should send imagePath as parameter and not the full list, like:

```
                     for imagePath in imagePathList:
                          copyPicMain(imagePath)
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: There's a new mistake. I've edited it again. Please have a look.

Comment: the mistake I pointed was legit, why did you give me a negative vote ?

Comment: you made a mistake in 

`if __name__ == '__main__':

    imagePathList =    [r'C:\Users\strives\Desktop\panda.png',r'C:\Users\strives\Desktop\black.png',r'C:\Users\strives\Desktop\1.png']
for imagePath in imagePathList:
    copyPicMain(imagePath)`

add indention so the loop becomes under the `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: The code will not report errors, but the function is not implemented, but it's not bad.